# Using Expo SecureStore in React Native

Tags: react-native, security, expo

I have created an app with React Native CLI.
Now, I would like to store sensitive data and [SecureStore](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/) provides an API for securing data on mobile phones.

As I mentioned, the app has been created with React Native CLI. Do I have to do additional configuration to use SecureStore on the app or just `npm i expo-secure-store` and it is going to work.

If I would use EXPO, there is no additional configuration necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK if you are using a none expo project you have to install [unimodules](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-unimodules/) first.